# DIV Between List Items

Tags: html, css

**How can I place a div in between two list items, adding a margin on both sides?**

Here is the layout I am trying to achieve: [Link to Image](http://grab.by/fWPy)

Below is the code I am trying to use to make this happen.

```
<div id="logo">
  Logo Image
</div>

<div id="navigation">
  <ul>
   <li>Item 1</li>
   <li>Item 2</li>
   <li>Item 3</li>
   <li>Item 4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Is there a way to do this without adding individual styles to the 2nd and 3rd list items? That's the only way I can think of doing this.

Comment: Looking at the image: don't you have *two* lists, separated by a div?

Comment: I'd rather keep the navigation as one whole unordered list. The two list items on each side of the div are part of one navigation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the `<div>`, and give the `<li>` that you would want the `<div>` in its class:

http://jsfiddle.net/charlescarver/jTYnW/

```
<div id="navigation">
  <ul>
   <li>Item 1</li>
   <li>Item 2</li>
   <li id="logo">
        Logo Image
   </li>
   <li>Item 3</li>
   <li>Item 4</li>
  </ul>
</div>​
```

Comment: That's what I was thinking as I was typing out the question. What was holding me back was that the logo div has 2 headers (h1, h2) with a title and subheadline for the site (hidden with text indent). Not 100% sure if that's a big deal removing those elements (ie, SEO?), but I think I'm going to take this div-removal route anyway.

Comment: You can still put the `<h1>` and `<h2>` tags in the `<li>` tag.

Comment: @CharlesTruelson - From a semantic perspective, I prefer your original idea of styling the `li`s. If your logo isn't truly part of your list, you shouldn't mark it up as if it was.

Comment: @Alohci, this is true. However, I figured I can make it part of the list as a "Home" link. I included the site title and subhead (`h1`, `h2`) in their own div, and used `display: none`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this code

```
<ul>
        <li>
            <div>test</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div>test</div>
        </li>
        <li class="specific">
            <div>test</div>
        </li>
         <li>
            <div>test</div>
        </li>
</ul>
```

Adjust css to div